# Was the identical beaker enough for Dr. Mora Pol to recognize Odo as sentient?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* S02E12 "The Alternate", after studying Odo in his natural goo form for seven years, Dr. Mora was forced to recognize Odo as sentient when, one morning, after noticing Odo's disappearance from the beaker where he was contained, a replica of the empty beaker appears next to it.

Without knowing Odo's shape-shifting abilities yet, it doesn't appear that obvious to relate him with a glass beaker. It could have happened, for example, that someone else have taken Odo and placed an identical beaker aside Odo's empty one. I just want to know if the identical beaker was enough for Dr. Mora Pol to recognize Odo as sentient or if he applied a reasoning/deduction or a kind of test to the beaker, I don't know, like Macready did in The Thing?

Comment: Note that Doctor Mora is full of crap and has a very high opinion of his own capacities

Comment: @Valorum tell us how you really feel ;)

Comment: Probably not enough to recognise sentience, but after reviewing the video that should have been constantly recording he probably realised there was something interesting going on.